# Google Maps Location API address autocomplete and show picked result

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I had this code working earlier. Basically it gives a location autocomplete, which still works perfectly, and shows the result in a small map in a `div`.

I just observed this issue, reproduced in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/980p6b9x/1/). Once I pick the location, it gives me the map div, but it's completely gray. The exact same code was working earlier, am I loading the map API from an experimental place or my code is referencing to something what has changed?

HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input type='text' id='autocompleteLocation'/>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:200px; display:none;"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    initializeLocation();
});

// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;

function initializeLocation() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
    // to geographical location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocompleteLocation')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        getAddressPlace();
    });
}

function getAddressPlace() {
    $('#map-canvas').fadeIn();
    lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.k;
    lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.D;

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Entered location'
    });      
}
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/980p6b9x/1/

**UPDATE**

So in the function `getAddressPlace()` if I update the `lat` and `lgn`variable initialization to:

```
lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.G;
lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.K;
```

I found the values after a bit of debugging. Now it works. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/980p6b9x/2/)
Clearly my way to get lat ang lng values is wrong. What is the correct way?

**UPDATE**

I found it:

```
lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
```

So the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/980p6b9x/4/

However, it would be delightful to know what are those properties, why are they "public" and why would their name change?

Comment: Do not use undocumented properties of the API in your code (`location.G`, `location.K`), use the documented functions (.`lat()`, `.lng()`).  The undocumented properties can (and do) change with every release of the API.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not supposed to use undocumented properties of the API. Very good point.
As I stated in the question too, I changed my calls to get latitude and longitude to the following:

```
lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
```

Works fine, and seems much more reliable than the earlier code.
Thanks for the help!

<kbd>[Final result fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/980p6b9x/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.G;
lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.K;
```

I do not have reference why yours code:

```
lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.k;
lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.D;
```

does not work, I just did:

> console.log(JSON.stringify(autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location));

which printed out:

> {"G":51.5073509,"K":-0.12775829999998223}

Comment: Thanks, I went a very similar way `console.log(autocomplete.getPlace())` (in Chrome) and browsing there in Chrome. But since this code was woring earlier, I suppose this would solve it just for a while. Then I found `autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat()` and `autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng()`. That's what I needed.